# Get USDC Metadata

Tags: metaplex, metadata, usdc

I can get the metadata of any token I build like that:

```
import { Metaplex, keypairIdentity } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';
import { Metadata } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
  .use(keypairIdentity(wallet))

const metadataPda = metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({ mint: mint });
const account = await Metadata.fromAccountAddress(connection, metadataPda);

console.log('Name', account.data.name)
console.log('Symbol', account.data.symbol)
console.log('URI', account.data.uri)
```

It is a very simple code and works.

I am trying to get the metadata of very popular tokens like USDC on Devnet. I would like to get and show this information like [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/address/Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr?cluster=devnet) or [Solscan](https://solscan.io/token/Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr?cluster=devnet). But, when I try it, I receive an error "Unable to find Metadata account".

Even, on Solscan, you do not see any metadata in the [corresponding tab](https://solscan.io/token/Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr?cluster=devnet#metadata).

It seems the metadata of this token does not work in the same way. How I can get the name, symbol and image of USDC Dev?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metadata for that particular mint was added using the token-list prior to the adoption of the Metaplex Token Metadata program as the preferred way of adding metadata to a token. As a result, it cannot be retrieved using the Metaplex SDK because it does not have a metadata account.

The metadata for that mint can be found on line 120875 of the now deprecated token-list.
https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list/blob/main/src/tokens/solana.tokenlist.json

```
{
  "chainId": 103,
  "address": "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr",
  "symbol": "USDC-Dev",
  "name": "USD Coin Dev",
  "decimals": 6,
  "logoURI": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/assets/mainnet/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v/logo.png",
  "tags": [
    "stablecoin"
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "blog": "https://medium.com/credix/building-an-spl-token-faucet-on-solana-2b8a07d364ff",
    "coingeckoId": "usd-coin"
  }
},
```

To clarify, there isn't an official devnet version of USDC. Rather, what exists is a mint that someone created on devnet which uses the same metadata as USDC. It's important to keep in mind that anyone can create new tokens with metadata that imitates real tokens. Ultimately, its the mint address that serves as the token's unique identifier.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the explanations! So, is it possible get this information from any service or API? I am building an app similar to Solana Explorer.
I think, an alternative is to build my own API and persist this json in a BBDD.

Comment: This looks like it might have what you're looking for (although haven't personally used before): https://github.com/solflare-wallet/utl-aggregator